# Mathematical Operations Without Using Java Math Class

Tags: java, math

I've been making my own class library in Java and I've run into a small annoyance. The library is centered around *math*. I started with the intention of not using the *Java Math Class*. Unfortunately, my lack of skill paired with my inability to find a resource online that tackles this problem has resulted in me falling back onto the Java Math Class. **Is there a way I can do logarithms without using Math.log?**

Comment: with or without?

Comment: @jhamon Oops! I meant without.

Comment: Can you name a usecase in which this is required? You can probably use a static import to avoid typing `Math.`

Comment: Why _don't_ you want to use `Math`?

Comment: Either you use the Java math library, you use some other library, or you implement it yourself.

Comment: There is a "way" but you'll end-up copying the `Math` implementation.
Fun note: "Maxx - Get a way" song was playing in the background hahaha

Comment: Well, you can always copy the source code of Math.log and copy it into a TotallyNotMath.log class/method. The question is of course what would be the point of doing that.

Comment: Why would you do this? Lesson one in software development: don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Maybe you can try it ? https://coderanch.com/t/651041/java/Logarithm-java-Math-log

Comment: @NickJ I just think it would be interesting to know how to this to get a better understanding of how it's done.

Comment: @JohnathanDavidow reading/debugging the `Math` sources is a good way to learn, if that's the intent.

Comment: And if you want to implement logarithms yourself, be very careful. See https://floating-point-gui.de/ for a small tour of the hazard. And before your chime in with "I'll be careful," Please remember this classic dialogue: "Luke Skywalker: I'll be careful. Dr. Evazan: You'll be dead!"

Comment: @JohnathanDavidow: you can't learn "how it's done" by re-implementing it in Java, because `Math` is not implemented in Java (well, there is Java source code, but most of the actual code is hidden deep in your JVM implementation, as most of the methods in Math are implemented using so-called intrinsics).

Comment: @JohnathanDavidow the place to start would be to understand how to calculate things like logarithms, sines, cosines etc from series expansion, so you can just use basic arithmetic, and that is more Maths related than software.

Comment: This might give you an idea of how to do it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977586/is-there-an-approximation-to-the-natural-log-function-at-large-values

Comment: @LppEdd That is my intent. I think the way I worded the question may have been confusing. Thank you.

Comment: @NickJ *Don't reinvent the wheel unless you plan on learning more about wheels.

Comment: @Sweeper This is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try to use a power series as per: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61283

For example:

```
@Test
public void printMathCalculation() {
    double libValue = Math.log(100); 
    double myValue = getLn(100);

    System.out.println("Actual: \t" + libValue);
    System.out.println("Approximate: \t" + myValue);
}

//Take double to an integer power
private double pow(double num, int power) {
    double result = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
        result *= num;
    }
    return result;
}

//Get natural log
private double getLn(double num) {
    int accuracy = 1000;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < accuracy; n++) {
        double num1 = (1.0/(2*n+1));
        double num2 = (num-1)/(num+1);

        sum += num1*pow(num2,2*n+1);
    }

    return 2 * sum;
}
```

The results I get are:

```
Actual:         4.605170185988092 
Approximate:    4.605170185988078
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using simple maths to calculate

```
public static int toLog2N(int num){
    return num > 1 ? 1 + toLog2N(num/2) : 0;
}
```

It's just an example: you should use the `Math` class as it provides different methods like `log(double a), log10(double a), log1p(double a)`. It will make your code more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: It does help. Thank you!

Comment: OP said he doesn't want to use Math. In your code there is a variable `n` that comes from nowhere. Your code returns `int`, that means for example `toLog2N(4) = toLog2N(5) = toLog2N(6) = toLog2N(7)`which is false. `Maths.log(x)` is log base e, not log base 2

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yep. That's me.

Comment: `Math`/`StrictMath` are the only ways without using JNI/JNA/JNR/JNHW to utilize the floating point coprocessor instructions for math. Otherwise you have to do manual taylor series or another approximation which are slow.  It's why your pocket calculators are so much slower at sqrt/log/sin/ than primitive operations.